# when I hit render image, it doesn't start rendering

Tags: rendering

the window where the rendering happens pops up but nothing gets rendered. I tried with other blend files and there it still works, so I don't know what's up, I would appreciate help.

here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Since we have absolutely no idea what you are trying to render you aren't likely to get any suggestions! Some more details and adding a link to your blend file to your question would help.  Grab the URL of the question. Go to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/ ). Select your blend file. Add the url of the question. Grab the url that results. Go back to the question and edit it. Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I downloaded and am rendering something but it's taking a loooong time to render. Have you waited long enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the huge number of modifiers you have on your objects. I disabled them all, and the render started without issues. Try applying them and removing ones that aren't necessary.

Comment: you were right, it works now! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't download the blender file but did you check the outliner and make sure the "render" icon is turned on? This might be the cause.

[image: outliner]

Comment: i had it turned on, figured out the problem now but thank you anyways! :)

Comment: Well post your solution so other people know! ;)

Comment: the problem was that I had lots of unapplied modifiers.